# Sum as long as sum doesn't exceed a value

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I have a list of card of a certain value that goes from 0.5, 1-2...7.
I need to pick every time the loop goes a random card from the list and do the sum of the values as many times as possible but the sum mustn't exceed `sum < 7.5`and every time i have to pop the card from the list.

I tried this way:
(switcher is a function that finds the value of a card and sums it to `sum`)

```
    while sum < 7.5:
        card_picked = cards[random.randrange(len(cards))]
        sum = switcher(card, sum)
        card_index = cards.index(card)
        cards.pop(card_index)
```

But this gives me every time a value bigger than 7.5.
Any ideas?

Comment: the `switcher` returns the `sum`?

Comment: That's because your loop only stops *after* you've already exceeded the sum, you need to test what the sum would be if you actually picked the new card, and stop *before* you add it to the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of picking one card at a time, you can simple shuffle all your cards and always `pop()` the first one - thats better then picking one random one and getting it index later on:

```
import random

cards = [.5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

# shuffle the whole cards list into a new random configuration
pickings = random.sample(cards,k=len(cards)) 

s = 0
c = []
while True: # they eventually add up to more then 7.5 so no need to check for empty list
    card = pickings.pop(0) # get first
    if s + card < 7.5:     # can add?
        s += card            # do so
        c.append(card)       # and to list so we see the cards collected
    else:
        print("cant take ", card) # cant, break while
        break

print ("Sum:",s)
print(c)
```

Some runs:

```
cant take  4
Sum: 3.5
[3, 0.5]

cant take  3
Sum: 5
[4, 1]

cant take  7
Sum: 2.5
[0.5, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding to `sum` (which by the way, it would be best to rename, because you're overshadowing the name of the builtin function `sum()` there)  and **then**, next time you hit the top of the loop, you're checking whether it has gone over the limit. So you're exiting the loop if and only if it has *already* gone over.  So naturally you will always exit the loop in the state of having `sum > 7.5`. You could re-formulate your `while` condition so that it is evaluated after the new card value is known, but before `sum` is updated.   Or you could leave it as-is but keep track of the last card added: then, once you're outside the loop subtract its value from `sum` and put the card back into the deck.